# undefined local variable or method autocomplete path rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete gem to populate the data while entering the text.
i followed [autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) doc.
In my ***routes*** i added

```
gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete'
```

in ***downloads_controller***

```
  autocomplete :downloads, :fund, :full => true
```

in ***application.js***

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

in ***routes*** file

```
 resources :downloads do
  get :autocomplete_downloads_fund, :on => :collection
end
```

in ***view***

```
<%autocomplete_field_tag 'fund', '', downloads_autocomplete_path, :size => 75%>
```

when i run this i ***get***,

> undefined local variable or method `downloads_autocomplete_path' for #<#

my rake routes

```
autocomplete_downloads_fund_downloads GET    /downloads/autocomplete_downloads_fund(.:format) downloads#autocomplete_downloads_fund
                        downloads GET       /downloads(.:format)                                downloads#index
```

here downloads is a table name and fund is the attribute name,

Download is the model name

can anyone help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the link:

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'fund', '', autocomplete_downloads_fund_downloads_path, :size => 75 %>
```

Check all available routes:

```
rake routes
```

Comment: Paste output of `rake routes`

Comment: That's another issue. You can add a new question and paste link here (if you like to)

Comment: @vjnan369 On SO, you should maintain the individuality of each question. So that others can get benefit from your question. Let's not make it a thread.